# Receiving server broadcast on mobile in real time

Tags: java, blackberry, mobile, symbian

I have to write a simple mobile application that is able to receive broadcast from a server, connected using GPRS, over a secure SSL connection.

The amount of data the mobile needs to receive is very small (a string of about 100 characters length for a single broadcast and maximum 10 broadcasts per minute).

I need to display it on screen, generate an alert sound, and vibrate the device.

The client doesn't need to send anything back to the server. (Of course, at the time of initialization the client app needs to send some data for authorization.)

The target mobile platforms are Symbian S60 and Blackberry.

How can I do this? What tools, SDK and third-party framework (if any) should I use?

I am familiar with Java and network programming but not for mobile devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java ME can probably be use to connect a secure socket to the server. Of course you need to keep it alive all the time as their is no easy way for the server to initiate a connection.

If you need the server to initiate the connection you can use SIP, but I don't think there are any Symbian S60 devices that support the SIP API for Java ME (JSR-180). Symbian has a C++ SIP API.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the [BlackBerry Push API](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/pushapi.jsp).  It is available for both native apps as well as widgets.